# Best way to implement Facebook pixel event tracking in PrestaShop

Tags: facebook, prestashop, facebook-marketing-api

Hello I've recently added a Facebook pixel at one of our site built with PrestaShop. I've added the default pixel code with the page view event on all pages and separate events on various pages (purchase,  add to cart and so). The event code is in javascript. I've added only the page view event as an img tag,  the other tracks are  called only with javascript. The thing is i get irrelevant statics in Facebook comparison with the ones I get from PrestaShops back office. The code looks good (I've deluged it with Facebook pixel extention for chrome). I have to place both the img tag and the javascript code for every event in order to cover the fallback? (no js) When i try so the debugger issues errors. Can someone provide a sample code for 2 events? The Facebook documentation is a bit misleading because they have references in the old and new pixel .
Code in header :

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    {literal}
    <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    {/literal}

    fbq('init', 'pixel_code_here');
    fbq('track', "PageView");
    {$product_page_facebook_tracking['js_event']}
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
            src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=pixel_code_here&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        />
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

From the product controller:

```
$facebook_event = "fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
        content_name: '$product_name',
        content_category: '$product_category_name',
        content_type: 'product',
        content_ids: ['$product_id'], 
        value: $product_price,
        currency: 'EUR',
        referrer: document.referrer,
        userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
        language: navigator.language,
    });";

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'product_page_facebook_tracking' => array(
            'js_event' => $facebook_event,
        ),
    ));
```

The error i get is that the pixel did not load.
The above code is to fire the event when in product page, i fire the fbq with javascript, do i have to add a second  with the event for fallback? If yes where?

Comment: Please, show some code in your question as well as the errors shown in your debugger.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Could you please share a solution? Cheers